# Is there any low cost option available for neo4j auradb enterprise on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Neo4j auradb enterprise on aws , any low cost options available to start with limited resources (currently $70K+ it is showing in contract).

Can someone help me by adding your suggestions and guidance on this.

Comment: Contact AWS support

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary it seems to be something that Neo4J bills, not AWS

Comment: That said, Neo4J AuraDB literally has two "low cost options for getting started", and those are the ones that are **not enterprise**. Enterprise is the high cost option! So I'm not sure why you are asking for the low cost high cost option?

Comment: @user253751 Thanks for answering , just wondering since starting minimal cost itself is 70K+ for enterprise. (So though of checking If I am missing any other enterprise options)

Comment: Make sure it's on a virtual server and avoid a cluster install which creates a minimum of 3 instances.

Comment: The price for Neo4J AuraDB Enterprise is "contact our sales team." I guess you already contacted their sales team and they said $70K. Did you contact their sales team again, and ask them if there is a trial version? I suppose they will tell you that the other two non-enterprise options are the trial version. But maybe they will co-operate with you. You must be representing a decently-sized company, if "contact our sales team" did not scare you off.

Answer (score 0):

[GrapheneDB](https://www.graphenedb.com/) - A third party provider for Managed Neo4j on AWS.
Lower cost Plans from Neo4j for DBaaS - [Neo4j Aura Free and Aura Professional Plans](https://neo4j.com/pricing/)